# Convex Hull for known output size in O(n)

Tags: convex-hull

Given a set $S$ of $n$ planar points, we know that the $|CH(S)| = 17$. How can I create an algorithm that computes $CH(S)$ in $O(n)$ time? Why is it really $O(n)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Optimal_output-sensitive_algorithms

Comment: @D.W. Thanks. I was thinking the same, the reason why it's $O(n)$ is stupidly simple, $log(17)$ being constant. So I thought maybe I'm missing something.